# Access MYSQL from .htaccess

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, ip, block

I am trying to block access to my site from htaccess level. I am looking to read bad IP's from a MySQL table then limit access using that.

1. Is this a safe method to use?
2. How do I create a connection from htaceess?

I have checked previous similar question but non have the actual connection code

Thanks

Comment: htaccess can't connect to MySQL.

Comment: Thanks, I will give the link a try. It might just be a secure idea to stick to php to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for `.htaccess` to use data stored in MySQL table directly. You could however use `mod_ext_filter` (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ext_filter.html) which allows you to filter request (with `mode` set to `input`) by arbitrary extenal program. This program could connect to MySQL and verify whether IP exists in denial table.

(For performance sake consider:

- developing custom Apache module
- caching list of denied IPs in text-file)

Comment: so you mean i can read the results of a php file then use it in htaccess?

Comment: no, you can verify whether request comes from valid IP before it even reaches php. .htaccess has nothing to do here.

Comment: Is that possible on a shared host?

Comment: it depends on how well you go with this host's administrator. ;-) as a last resort you could regurarly overwrite .htaccess with content from MySQL (as WebnetMobile suggested) or simply verify IP address at the very beginning of every PHP script - and PHP's `auto_prepend_file` option can come useful then.

Comment: Ok, I think I will stick with the verify IP for every script method. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You cannot connect from `.htaccess` . `.htaccess` is configuration file. It's NOT executed but processed. All you can do is run cronjob that **creates** `.htaccess` file as needed.

Answer (score 1):

i guess, you could try this. I have never tried myself though 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap

Answer (score -3):

> Is this a safe method to use?

by 'safe' do you mean 'secure'? if so, then no, its not secure at all, if by 'safe' you meant will it harm your system or damage it in any major way then 'yes, it's safe'

> How do I create a connection from htaceess?

it runs when you connect to a file or folder on your server.